# How to stop zsh from reprinting the previous command

Tags: zsh

Consider the following bash interaction:

```
cat file.txt
rm !$
```

When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the `rm` command, the command executes immediately. zsh on the other hand, does not execute the command, but it will display the command with the token `!$` expanded to `file.txt`, like this:

```
rm file.txt
```

That requires me to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time. Is there a way to make zsh behave like bash in this case?

Comment: You can also use Alt-. to fill in the final argument of the previous command immediately, rather than waiting for `!$` to be expanded when the command is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have `histverify` turned on. You can turn it off by

```
unsetopt histverify
```